# SQL, how to INSERT INTO table from a specific start number ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert some rows from one table to another, here is the structure for both tables:

- ID (int)
- courseID (int)
- course (bit)
- bookmark (varchar(100))
- course_date (datetime)
- posttest (bit)
- post_attempts (int)

The ID column is a primary key with auto increment, so if I use 
`INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2`, 
sql generates this error **#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'**.

Well I can omit the ID column but the problem is that new ID is autogenerated. I have ID references in another table so my question is: Is there a way to specifiying a START number for the ID when I type the command below?

```
INSERT INTO table1(
    course_id,
    course,
    bookmark,
    course_date,
    posttest,
    post_attempts
)
SELECT
    course_id,
    course,
    bookmark,
    course_date,
    posttest,
    post_attempts
FROM table2
```

Comment: if TSQL, use SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON and SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 OFF

Comment: Hi, could you please show me how to do integrating into my code...I'm a newbie on sql. Thanks

Comment: If you are not ensuring distinct `ID`s for each table how will you manage to map your relationships???

Comment: indeed I need distinct ID...that's why I asked if is it possible to set a start ID number, so rows start from that point to auto increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase the `ID` value for new inserted data do this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(
    ID,
    course_id,
    course,
    bookmark,
    course_date,
    posttest,
    post_attempts
)
SELECT
    ID + 1000 AS ID,
    course_id,
    course,
    bookmark,
    course_date,
    posttest,
    post_attempts
FROM table2
```

But if you want to skip some starting values you can use `WHERE` clause when selecting:

```
...
FROM table2
WHERE ID > 10
```

Comment: ID is auto_increment field, you can't explicit in INSERT statement

Comment: You can explicit auto increment field only if you disable auto increment

Comment: I did test it and it works without disable the auto increment...THANKS EVERYONE, I love you guys

Answer (score 0):

You can set the auto_increment start value as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

For further information please go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)